# Unable to uninstall AVG after rollback to Windows 7 from Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, anti-virus, uninstall, avg-antivirus

I recently rolled back to Windows 7 Professional after upgrading to Windows 10, using to 'Go Back to Windows 7' option in Windows 10.

Since then, whenever Windows 7 starts, AVG Antivirus (Free Edition, version 16.91.7688) would say : "Because you've upgraded the system, reinstall is required. "

[image]

When I click on 'Reinstall', it would go online and download a good 55 MB or so. After that, while trying to install, it would ask 'Repair' or 'Uninstall'.

[image]

When 'Uninstall' is chosen, after a while, it would come up with the message : 'Uninstallation failed. Description : General Error. 0x064C. Error code 0xC007064C'.

[image]

Similar message for a repair attempt as well. Since I am on a free version, I can't even post this on their forum or avail the option of 'have someone install it for you' which they provide with the error message. Why can't things exit graciously ?!

AVG Virus Definitions Update go through fine and I am uptodate.

I do have a Clonezilla dump of the Windows 7 partition, before the upgrade. I am wondering whether I would have to restore it for the sake of a simple antivirus installation issue.

Comment: Can you delete the programm the old fashioned way via Control-Panel - Software/Programms or do you receive the same error? Have you tried the [official AVG-Remover](http://www.avg.com/ww-en/utilities)?

Comment: Yes, the official AVG Remover worked. (The control panel option had not worked before). Silly me, I didn't look for a AVG Remover myself. Thank you so much. SE rocks! 
May I request you to put your comment as an answer, so that I can mark it as a correct answer for the benefit of posterity ?

Comment: @benjaminS Please see WhirlMind's response asking you to add your commented suggestion as an answer for acceptance since that worked to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using the AVG Remover

AVG provides a tool to remove AVG installations.
You can [download the **AVG Remover** on their website](http://www.avg.com/ww-en/utilities).
You may need to reboot your computer afterwards.
All your user-settings and all files related to AVG will be removed forcefully by this tool.